# How to get the starting position of a node using lxml?

Tags: lxml

Say I have an xml file

```
<xml>
    <data> 
        <info>bla bla </info>
    <data>
</xml>
```

How can I get the position(column number) of  tag?

Answer (score 0):

Since

```
<xml>
    <data> 
        <info>bla bla </info>
    <data>
</xml>
```

is equivalent to

```
<xml><data><info>bla bla </info><data></xml>
```

(and incountable other ways of formating the same tree) this is impossible. There are no rows or columns in XML.